# Previewing single lights in blender (cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

I am looking for a way to quickly disable all but one emission source on a scene to gauge how much of an impact it is on the overall scene.

I can hide other light emitting objects and change environment to black and then unhide all but what I'm looking for is a single shortcut. Like for example, Ctrl+Shift+Click on a node will preview just the node (with the Node Wrangler addon). I'd like to be able to click/shortcut on an object and have only its emission shown.

Comment: If lights you want to hide are of lamp type you can control them via *Lighter's Corner* in the Scene tab. If those are meshes with Emission shader that won't work and you can do that only by hiding those meshes via Outliner.